# Can't kill jackdbus auto, because it auto starts everytime

Tags: xubuntu, pulseaudio, process, jack, killall

(edit) Topic closed:
It wasn't a problem with jackdbus auto.
In [this thread](https://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?t=15276) I accidentally found a hint that, without me noticing, the server name changed itself from "(default)" to "voreingestellt" (, which is german for "default".)

---

Preabmle:
I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS xenial
Kernel: 4.4.0 Lowlatency

Problem:
It all starts with the error

```
Ignoring JACK server start request because server is already started.
```

when I want to start the PulseAudio Bridge in Cadence.
I had this before and killing jackdbus auto allowed me to start a fresh instance and got it working (as fragile and unstable as jack works then).
However, I am absolutely unable to kill jackdbus auto, no matter what I do.

1. Taskmanager > right-click > kill
2. kill *pid*
3. kill -9 *pid*
4. killall jackdbus
5. killall -9 jackdbus

2 and 4 do absolutely nothing.
1, 3 and 5 cause the process to be killed but being auto started again right away with a new pid.
Since it's called jackdbus **auto** I can assume that it starts **auto**matically but how in the world am I supposed to solve the error/message when trying to start PulseAudio Bridge in Cadence?

Comment: try `sudo systemctl stop jackdbus`, then `sudo systemctl disable jackdbus`

Comment: @George foobar@linux:~$ sudo systemctl stop jackdbus  
Failed to stop jackdbus.service: Unit jackdbus.service not loaded.  
foobar@linux:~$ sudo systemctl disable jackdbus  
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/pulse/default.pa` contains

```
### Automatically connect sink and source if JACK server is present
.ifexists module-jackdbus-detect.so
.nofail
load-module module-jackdbus-detect channels=2
.fail
.endif
```

You can comment those lines out and that should prevent auto-loading to jackdbus by Pulse Audio.